# count occurrence of repeated values in a column with multiple column in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, group-by, partition

How to return count of repeated values in a column of two database table in MySQL? Suppose a row of column 1 contains value 'a' and row of column 2 contains value 'b' similarly another row of column 1 contains value 'a' and row of column 2 contains value 'b' then I want count to be returned as 2. over partition by is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do a simple aggregation?

```
select col1, col2, count(*)
from t
group by col1, col2;
```

Or are you trying to append this value to each row:

```
select t.*, tsum.cnt
from t join
     (select col1, col2, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by col1, col2
     ) tsum
     on tsum.col1 = t.col1 and tsum.col2 = t.col2;
```

Comment: simple aggregation is what i need but further i need only the maximum count value to be returned and only if it is greater than some value

Comment: @carefree . . . Then add `order by count(*) limit 1` to get the highest count.

Comment: it is returning the lowest count, any idea to get highest count?